# Type hinting structs as traits

Tags: rust

I have a method (`Journal.next_command()`) who's signature returns the `Command` trait. In the method I am attempting to return an instance of the `Jump` struct, which implements the `Command` trait:

```
trait Command {
    fn execute(&self);
}

struct Jump {
    height: u32,
}

impl Command for Jump {
    fn execute(&self) {
        println!("Jumping {} meters!", self.height);
    }
}

struct Journal;

impl Journal {
    fn next_command(&self) -> Command {
        Jump { height: 2 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let journal = Journal;
    let command = journal.next_command();
    command.execute();
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
src/main.rs:19:9: 19:27 error: mismatched types:
 expected `Command`,
    found `Jump`
(expected trait Command,
    found struct `Jump`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:19         Jump { height: 2 }
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I inform the compiler that `Jump` implements `Command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return unboxed traits at the moment, they need to be wrapped in some sort of container.

```
fn next_command(&self) -> Box<Command> {
    Box::new(Jump { height: 2 })
}
```

This works.

Comment: It's not a matter of “at the moment”; returning an unsized type just can't make sense. So you need to return either the concrete type or a boxed trait object. That will not change.

Comment: I wasn't exactly sure the status of this, I've seen complaints and discussion about this limitation.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan it depends on what you mean by 'returning an unsized type'. There is a (postponed) ["Add unsized return values" RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/977).

Comment: And, more specific to this question, https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/518